# Can I save scale settings between startups in ImageJ using start-up macros?

Tags: macros, imagej

I have just recently started using ImageJ (or Fiji so be more specific) to measure the size of diatom shells in microscope photographs. It was pretty straight-forward to set the global scale using a reference photograph of a micrometer scale and then simply use the line tool to measure my diatoms. The only issue is that every time I start the program I have to reset the scale and I would prefer to avoid both the extra hassle, but also the issue of me calibrating a bit differently every time. I found the start-up macro builder and if I could make it set the scale to 164.4 pixels per micrometer I would be one happy hippo. Unfortunately I'm pretty illiterate when it comes to the language of computers. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...) (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*) to get the code needed to achieve that:

```js
run("Set Scale...", "distance=164.4 known=1 pixel=1 unit=um global");
```

If you plan to put this into your `StartupMacros.txt`, be aware that the command requires at least one image to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

For setting the scale upon startup, Jan's hint is great.

For the case where you have different scales (you said yours might be different each time), you can try this FIJI plugin I made a while back: [FIJI Plugins: Microscope Measurement Tools](http://fiji.sc/Microscope_Measurement_Tools)

This plugin allows you to save Scales that you use frequently, and apply them with a pop-up window that lists your saved scales.

The Instructions tell you how to install it & set up your calibrations file the first time.

Comment: FYI, there was an older plugin that provided similar functionality called "Microscope Scale", but unfortunately it's ease-of-use broke at some point, when the ability to compile jython plugins from the FIJI menu went away. Hence the new plugin that doesn't hard-code the scales, but instead uses a text configuration file.